# Append tag name (version number) to Zip file in git post-receive hook

Tags: git, git-post-receive

In Git, I'm trying to get the version number of my commit (by using tags) in a post-receive hook.

Once I get that tag, I want to zip a certain directory and append the version number to it (ex: myplugin-2.0.1.zip) but I'm not sure how to get the tag of the commit in the post-receive hook.

Does anyone know how to properly get the tag name of a commit inside a post-receive hook?

Here's what I have so far, but the SOME_WAY_OF_GETTING_TAG_NAME is where I'm confused.

```
#!/bin/bash
_version=SOME_WAY_OF_GETTING_TAG_NAME
zip -r myplugin-$_version.zip plugin_repo/
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The post-receive hooks gets as input from stdin

```
<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
```

refname always contain ref, if you tagged, it will be `refs/tags/TAGNAME`